# How to make a post or share button on Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook just driving me crazy! I have no idea, what they are trying to get from me. The thing is that I want to is to make SHARE button inside my Android app. What code I should write in order to get similar window?
This is the pic what I wanna do:
http://s29.postimg.org/pvgbhv1dz/151020_0002.png

This is the code how I do it now:

```
case FB_ID:
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            fbCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(fbCallbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "FB");
                            openFragment(MakeWallPostFragment.newInstance(social_id,null), false);
                            // App code
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // App code
                            finish();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            // App code
                        }
                    });
            break;
```

This code give me this kind of error:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions")); //this is the culprit string gives me:
```

The publish_actions permissions are missing, 
    the share will fail unless this app was authorized to publish in another installation. this error
What should I use to make it happen?
Btw, this is the video with explanation, but I think all this stuff is deprecated now:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBBVkwBeaY4

Comment: Add a button to your app, and make it invoke the [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)